# Is this a proper use of 'concept'?

Tags: grammaticality

From "*[Printing Technologies for Medical Applications](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26856235)*":

> In proton therapy, for example, cancer cells and tumors are radiated directly by a beam of protons[67]. The physical **concepts** of the proton beam distinguish this method from other external radiotherapies. The physics of protons allow this technique to distribute energy only on cancer cells, reducing side effects.

Is this a proper use of 'concepts'? I would understand 'physical features', 'physical characteristics', 'physical aspects' but 'concepts'?

A concept is what a scientist can have in his mind.

Does the phrase intend to mean "because the physical concepts describing the behaviour of the proton beam tell us that it behaves differently from other beams.."?

Comment: I would not regard that as an appropriate use of "concept".

Comment: I'd also object to "distribute *on*"

Comment: "Of particular interest is proton beam therapy (PBT), as the physical properties of protons permit dose delivery at specific tissue depths. Protons deliver a low dose of energy when entering the body and deposit the bulk of their radiation energy at the end of their range of penetration, a phenomenon known as the "Bragg peak." By focusing delivery of radiation to the target tumor, it is believed that PBT may reduce toxicity associated with normal tissue damage." http://www.hca.wa.gov/hta/Pages/proton.aspx

Comment: A physical concept is what a physicist would have in his head.  As opposed to an artistic concept.  But the sentence is not well worded.

Comment: "Properties" would be better -- but if you subscribe to Plato's cave allegory then there may not be much of a distinction between the properties and the impression they make on us... blurry categories like that are common: Is the climate change a threat, or rather the climate *resulting* from the change? Can we talk about the topology of a place or wouldn't that be the *science*  describing its topography?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an appropriate use of the word concept.

> concept - a thought or idea ([src](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/concept))

I agree with [Peter A. Schneider](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/15471/peter-a-schneider) that the use of "properties" would be a better word choice.

However, the author may have intended to use concept as a modifier of 'photon beam'. In this example, they might have been referring to a concept as a beam/technology produced as an experimental model to test the viability of a new design feature (e.g. a concept car) (src: Apple Dictionary v2.2.1) . But this is far reaching and the sentence structure doesn't support this definition. Maybe it is a misprint.